# Checking a Pair Series values to see if they are in a List

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to check a pair of options and see if either one is in another list. I can check if each series individually is in a list, but then I do not know how to say something like `if x in list or y in list, then return True`

```
t1 = pd.Series(['A','B','C'],name='t1')
t2 = pd.Series(['E','F','G'],name = 't2')
test = pd.concat([t1,t2],axis=1)
include = ['A','F']

# create new column Included as
test["Included"] =
```

My First Idea (which does not work):

```
test['t1inc'] = test['t1'].isin(include)
test['t2inc'] = test['t1'].isin(include)
test['Included'] = ["Y" if x == True or y == True else "N" for x,y in test['t1inc'],test['t2inc']]
```

Desired Output:

```
    print(test)
    t1 t2 Included
0   A  E   True
1   B  F   True
2   C  G   False
```

Comment: Not really, but it is how the data is formatted to begin with. I am not comparing lists to a list, but a pair of series values to a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `isin` with `any`:

```
test['included'] = test.isin(include).any(1)

print(test)

 t1 t2  included
0  A  E      True
1  B  F      True
2  C  G     False
```

Comment: What do you mean by `any(1)`?

Comment: Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), it returns true if any is true